# Every $k$-chromatic graph has a $k$ -chromatic subgraph of min degree at least k−1

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof

**Claim :** To show that every [k-chromatic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) graph has a $k$-chromatic subgraph of min degree at least $k-1$.

**Proof** : let us assume that $G$ is $k$-chromatic graph but, it does not have a subgraph of min degree at least $k-1$, means min degree of every subgraph   of $G$ is less than equal to $k-2$. This is a contradiction to our assumption that graph $G$ is $k$-chromatic (why ?).

So I am looking for the proof of the claim given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you take a $k$-chromatic graph, and remove a vertex of degree $k-2$ or less, the result is still $k$-chromatic.

(Or, to put it the converse way: if you remove from a graph $G$ a vertex $v$ of degree $k-2$, and you can color $G - v$ with $k-1$ colors, then you can color $G$ with $k-1$ colors.)

Comment: But in a $k$ -chromatic graph, Is there always exist a vertex of degree $k-2$ or less. I think no for e.g. $k_5$ is 4 colourable but does not have a vertex of degree $2$.

Comment: Right. But if you have a $k$-chromatic graph with no vertices of degree $k-2$ or less, then you're happy: the entire graph is the subgraph you're looking for.

Comment: Proof by contradiction  :let us assume that graph is $k$ chromatic but after removing a vertex of degree $k-2$ or less , $G-v$ has a chromatic number strictly less than $k$, but if this is the case then I can color my original graph with less than $k$ colors, which is contradiction to our assumption.